Flutter: Mac OS 15 beta error in building iOS builds
I had updated my system to macOS 15 beta and now I'm getting on building flutter iOS builds. I'm using xcode 16 beta and I'm getting the following error.
`
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 15 in debug mode...
CocoaPods output:
### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.15.2
        Ruby : ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.x86_64-darwin24]
    RubyGems : 3.0.3.1
        Host : macOS 15.0 (24A5327a)
       Xcode : 16.0 (16A5171r)
         Git : git version 2.39.5 (Apple Git-151)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
```

### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.5
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.1
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.6.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0
```

### Podfile

```ruby
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
#   target 'RunnerTests' do
#     inherit! :search_paths
#   end
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

### Error

```
REXML::ParseException - #<TypeError: wrong argument type String (expected Regexp)>
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rexml-3.2.9/lib/rexml/source.rb:220:in `scan'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rexml-3.2.9/lib/rexml/source.rb:220:in `match'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rexml-3.2.9/lib/rexml/parsers/baseparser.rb:227:in `pull_event'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rexml-3.2.9/lib/rexml/parsers/baseparser.rb:207:in `pull'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rexml-3.2.9/lib/rexml/parsers/treeparser.rb:23:in `parse'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rexml-3.2.9/lib/rexml/document.rb:448:in `build'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rexml-3.2.9/lib/rexml/document.rb:101:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.24.0/lib/xcodeproj/workspace.rb:83:in `new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.24.0/lib/xcodeproj/workspace.rb:83:in `from_s'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.24.0/lib/xcodeproj/workspace.rb:66:in `new_from_xcworkspace'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator.rb:102:in `create_workspace'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator.rb:71:in `integrate!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:929:in `block in integrate_user_project'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:925:in `integrate_user_project'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:185:in `integrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:170:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
...
wrong argument type String (expected Regexp)
Line: 1
Position: 38
Last 80 unconsumed characters:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rexml-3.2.9/lib/rexml/parsers/treeparser.rb:96:in `rescue in parse'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rexml-3.2.9/lib/rexml/parsers/treeparser.rb:21:in `parse'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rexml-3.2.9/lib/rexml/document.rb:448:in `build'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rexml-3.2.9/lib/rexml/document.rb:101:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.24.0/lib/xcodeproj/workspace.rb:83:in `new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.24.0/lib/xcodeproj/workspace.rb:83:in `from_s'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.24.0/lib/xcodeproj/workspace.rb:66:in `new_from_xcworkspace'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator.rb:102:in `create_workspace'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/user_project_integrator.rb:71:in `integrate!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:929:in `block in integrate_user_project'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:925:in `integrate_user_project'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:185:in `integrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:170:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=%23%3CTypeError%3A+wrong+argument+type+String+%28expected+Regexp%29%3E%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Frexml-3.2.9%2Flib%2Frexml%2Fsource.rb%3A220%3Ain+%60scan%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Frexml-3.2.9%2Flib%2Frexml%2Fsource.rb%3A220%3Ain+%60match%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Frexml-3.2.9%2Flib%2Frexml%2Fparsers%2Fbaseparser.rb%3A227%3Ain+%60pull_event%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Frexml-3.2.9%2Flib%2Frexml%2Fparsers%2Fbaseparser.rb%3A207%3Ain+%60pull%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Frexml-3.2.9%2Flib%2Frexml%2Fparsers%2Ftreeparser.rb%3A23%3Ain+%60parse%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Frexml-3.2.9%2Flib%2Frexml%2Fdocument.rb%3A448%3Ain+%60build%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Frexml-3.2.9%2Flib%2Frexml%2Fdocument.rb%3A101%3Ain+%60initialize%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fxcodeproj-1.24.0%2Flib%2Fxcodeproj%2Fworkspace.rb%3A83%3Ain+%60new%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fxcodeproj-1.24.0%2Flib%2Fxcodeproj%2Fworkspace.rb%3A83%3Ain+%60from_s%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fxcodeproj-1.24.0%2Flib%2Fxcodeproj%2Fworkspace.rb%3A66%3Ain+%60new_from_xcworkspace%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fcocoapods-1.15.2%2Flib%2Fcocoapods%2Finstaller%2Fuser_project_integrator.rb%3A102%3Ain+%60create_workspace%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fcocoapods-1.15.2%2Flib%2Fcocoapods%2Finstaller%2Fuser_project_integrator.rb%3A71%3Ain+%60integrate%21%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fcocoapods-1.15.2%2Flib%2Fcocoapods%2Finstaller.rb%3A929%3Ain+%60block+in+integrate_user_project%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fcocoapods-1.15.2%2Flib%2Fcocoapods%2Fuser_interface.rb%3A64%3Ain+%60section%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fcocoapods-1.15.2%2Flib%2Fcocoapods%2Finstaller.rb%3A925%3Ain+%60integrate_user_project%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fcocoapods-1.15.2%2Flib%2Fcocoapods%2Finstaller.rb%3A185%3Ain+%60integrate%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fcocoapods-1.15.2%2Flib%2Fcocoapods%2Finstaller.rb%3A170%3Ain+%60install%21%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fcocoapods-1.15.2%2Flib%2Fcocoapods%2Fcommand%2Finstall.rb%3A52%3Ain+%60run%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fclaide-1.1.0%2Flib%2Fclaide%2Fcommand.rb%3A334%3Ain+%60run%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fcocoapods-1.15.2%2Flib%2Fcocoapods%2Fcommand.rb%3A52%3Ain+%60run%27%0A%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fcocoapods-1.15.2%2Fbin%2Fpod%3A55%3Ain+%60%3Ctop+%28required%29%3E%27%0A%2Fusr%2Flocal%2Fbin%2Fpod%3A23%3Ain+%60load%27%0A%2Fusr%2Flocal%2Fbin%2Fpod%3A23%3Ain+%60%3Cmain%3E%27%0A...%0Awrong+argument+type+String+%28expected+Regexp%29%0ALine%3A+1%0APosition%3A+38%0ALast+80+unconsumed+characters%3A%0A%3C%3Fxml+version%3D%221.0%22+encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
Searching for inspections failed: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 15.
Exited (1).
`

try flutter pub cache clean, flutter pub cache repair, flutter pub get, and pod install , retry building app fromxcode .

Make sure you have everything upto date,
Try:
<code>sudo gem install cocoapods<code>
then:

<code>flutter clean</code>
<code>flutter pub get</code>
<code>pod install</code>

